# Looping through agents in a queue

Tags: anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I'm new to Anylogic and Java, so I apologize in advance if this is a beginner question. I have one agent type that enters a queue (for example, called queue_X). I would like to loop through all the agents in the queue and perform some check on a parameter (that governs the removal of the agent from the queue). There may not be any agents in the queue in some instances.

This loop is set up inside an event that executes every X minutes.

What is the syntax for looping through the agents?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way:

```
for (int i=0; i< myQueue.size(); i++) {
    MyAgentType currentAgent = ((MyAgentType)myQueue.get(i));
}
```

This assumes there are only agents of type MyAgentType in your queue

Comment: Thank you Benjamin, I will give that a go tomorrow. Do I need to do a check on myQueue.size() to make sure its not empty before running the for loop or does the above already catch that?

Comment: if the size is 0, the loop does never do anything, as per Java defaults. Glad the answer was helpful. Please upvote this answer as “useful” (up-arrow next to the answer) to help other users find it in the future as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote for more info on how SOF works :)